# Running time of quicksort

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort

Suppose `B(n)` and `W(n)` are respectively the best case and worst case asymptotic running times for sorting an array of size n using `Quick Sort`. Consider the two statements:

> (1): `B(n)` is `O(W(n))`
>   (2): `B(n)` is `Theta(W(n))`

**Select ONE answer:**

> A. Both `(1)` and `(2)` are true
>   B. `(1)` is true but `(2)` is false
>   C. `(1)` is false but `(2)` is true
>   D. Both `(1)` and `(2)` are false

I think the answer is A but I am not sure

Comment: Hint: B(n) is O(nlogn) and W(n) is O(n^2). See whether B(n) is bounded by W(n) from above or below or both?

Comment: Why do you think the answer is A?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question with no evidence of work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B(n) = O(n * lg(n))

W(n) = O(n^2)

1) B(n) < W(n) implying B(n) = O(W(n)).

2) B(n) = Theta(W(n)) equals to W(n) = O(B(n)). As before B(n) < W(n), therefore W(n) is not bounded by B(n), making 2nd statement incorrect.

Solution is B, first statement is true and the second is false.

Comment: Downvoted. I don't believe Stack Overflow should be doing people's homework for them.

Comment: You are right but I am just answering the question. Downvote the question.